# How to get top layer information from getFeatureInfoUrl?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I am trying to get the feature information of the map that I clicked with the mouse using getFeatureInfoUrl from the openlayers.

But wherever I click, I get information about the bottom layer.
ex) The place I clicked on is Idc_gis:adhp_boundary below, but the information I want to know is idc_gis:adhp_buld.

How can only the highest layer present at the clicked point get information?
I found out using the QUERY_LAYERS property that only certain layers can get information, but when I name them with that property, I return the undefined if they are not in the click.

I only want to get information about the highest layer of layers that I've ever clicked on in a particular layers.

Here's my code. Thank you.

```
function addLayerTileWMS(layer_id, layer_name, visible, url, params){
    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({id : layer_id, name : layer_name});
    
    layer.setVisible(visible);
    layer.setSource(new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: url,
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            params: {
                'TILED': true,
                'VERSION': !params.version ? '1.1.0' : params.version,  // must be 1.1.0, not 1.3.0
                'SRS' : !params.srs ? this.getView().getProjection().getCode() : params.srs,    //Spatial Reference System  
                'FORMAT': !params.format ? 'image/png' : params.format,
                'TRANSPARENT': !params.transparent ? true : params.transparent,
                'LAYERS' : !params.layers ? '' : params.layers,
                'STYLES' : !params.styles ? '' : params.styles,
                'VIEWPARAMS' : !params.viewparams ? '' : params.viewparams,
                'CQL_FILTER' :  !params.cqlFilter ? null : params.cqlFilter 
            }
    }));
    return layer;
}


var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:5179',
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 20
    }),
    controls: []
});

var url = 'http://myurl/geoserver/wms';
var params = {layers : 'idc_gis:adhp_boundary,idc_gis:adhp_surface_a,idc_gis:adhp_surface_runway,idc_gis:adhp_buld,idc_gis:adhp_surface_ap', srs : 'EPSG:5179'}
var legendLayer = addLayerTileWMS("legendLayer", "legendLayer", true, url, params);

map.addLayer(legendLayer);

map.on('click', function(evt){
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();

    var layers = map.getLayers().getArray();
    for(var i=0; i<layers.length; i++){
        if(layers[i].get('name') == 'legendLayer'){
            legendSource = layers[i].getSource();
            var url = legendSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
                    coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
                    { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                    }
            );
            console.log(url);
        }
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Are you making a custom in-house app with a map feature? What exactly is the feature you are trying to expose to the end-user and what platform are you coding it in?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours of searching, I'm not sure it's a perfect solution, but I found a way.
The answer is the 'FEATURE_COUNT' attribute.

If you add this property, the URL you are returning contains json objects from all features you clicked on.
Then you can use the feature information of the last index in the whole json object list.

However, we cannot guarantee that the length of the json object list returned by clicking is less than the FEATURE_COUNT set.

```
for(var i=0; i<layers.length; i++){
        if(layers[i].get('name') == 'legendLayer'){
            legendSource = layers[i].getSource();
            var url = legendSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
                    coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
                    { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                      'FEATURE_COUNT':'9999',
                    }
            );
            console.log(url);
        }
    }
```

If the length of the json ovejct list returned by the click is greater than FEATURE_COUNT, you cannot be sure that the last json object is the information of the highest layer.

Set enough values

Answer (score 0):

In addition to needing to set the `FEATURECOUNT` parameter to a number greater than 1 if you intend to query more than one layer, it is possible to limit your query to just one layer by only adding that layer to the `QUERY_LAYERS` parameter.